# Помогите решить задачу по переменим в C#

Tags: c#

В этом задании необходимо написать программу, объявит две переменные: первая переменная - переменная целочисленного (int) типа со значением 99, вторая переменная - переменная действительного (double) типа со значением 0.3525. Перемножьте эти две переменные и результат выполнения назначьте двум новым переменным: целочисленного и вещественного типа. Выведите эти две последние переменные отдельно в новой строке в следующем порядке: целочисленная переменная, действительно переменная (каждое значение должно быть написано в новой строке без знаков препинания).

Мое решение не подходит

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a=99;
        double b=0.3525;
        var result = a*b;
        int c=result;
        double n=result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу в вашей программе проблем, за исключением отсутствия вывода и приведения: `int c = (int) result;`. Поскольку тут идет потеря точности, то нужно явно указывать приведение.

Comment: тогда я не понимаю, почему мой ответ не принимают

Comment: А вы его попробуйте скомпилировать... Можно например тут - https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void Main()
{
    int a=99;
    double b=0.3525;
    double result = a*b;
    int c=(int)result;
    double n=result;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Вам нужно прочитать про преобразование типов. [Ссылка](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.2.php).

Answer (score 0):

А можно еще "сосмекалить" и выдать вот такой код. Который тоже будет правильный)
var - это определение типа на этапе компиляции (строгая типизация никуда не пропадает)
К тому же не забудьте дописать Console.ReadLine(); иначе ваша консольное приложение мгновенно закроется после того как код отработает

```cs
        private static void Main()
        {
            var a = 99;
            var b = 0.3525;
            var result = a * b;
            var c = (int)result;
            var n = result;
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```